# Mathematica does not understand (R^3)^(1/3) is the same as R

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, variable-definitions, output

In the output from a calculation in mathematica stands `a/((R^3*c)^(1/3))`, with `c` and `a` constants and `R` the variable. Now I want to use the outputformula for a new calculation. But Mathematica does not understand that `(R^3)^(1/3)` is the same as `R`. So I don't get (correct) answers by using this formula. But when I replace `(R^3)^(1/3)` manually in the outputformula by `R`, then it works perfecty. My question is how I can manage that mathematica understands automatically `(R^3)^(1/3)`? 
I have already tried formulas like `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Collect` and much more formulas like that.

Comment: What if `R == -1` ?

Comment: Why do you think that `(R^3)^(1/3)` is the same thing that `R`?

Comment: @belisarius Phenomenal, our comments are the same time up to a second,only a fraction of a second apart.

Comment: And while I was typing my answer.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yeah, right :-)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm not so sure. Time and Space aren't what they used to be anymore http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.8144v1.pdf

Comment: This should have a canonical version...

Comment: @belisarius I've noticed that "bubbles" article gets printed here from time to time.

Comment: @Szabolcs It has. It's called "an algebra book".

Comment: @belisarius Perhaps @Szabolcs meant the combination of `Assumptions` and `FullSimplify`?

Comment: If my opinion counts for anything, I think this is fundamentally a math question and not a *Mathematica* one...

Comment: @Ajasja, if someone writes an answer with something like "*Mathematica* always assumes variables to be complex unless told otherwise" explicitly noted, maybe we can make this particular question canonical.

Comment: @J.M. I agree with you. Elitism is around the corner. Why should it be in an algebra book what the assumptions of Mathematica are? :-/

Answer (score 8):

If you make any assumptions you have to share them with *Mathematica* as well.
For Example:

```
Assuming[R > 0, FullSimplify[(R^3)^(1/3)]]
(*R*)
```

The default assumption is that all variables are complex. (As @J.M. noted in the comments).

Comment: Ahh... that too.

Comment: Ah thank you for your answers! I hadn't tought about that, because R means Radius. But now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It's just not always true that $(R^3)^{1/3} = R$.  How about $R=i$, for example?

```
N[(I^3)^(1/3)]

(* Out: 0.866025 - 0.5 I *)
```

If you expect this, you might have more luck with the real-valued `CubeRoot` function.  For example:

```
FullSimplify[CubeRoot[R^3]]

(* Out: R *)
```

Comment: In addition to being complex, it could be quaternion or even octonion.

Comment: Now, now, Gregory, if OP is still reeling from being introduced to complexes...

Comment: Doesn't Matmematica automatically assume that the symbol is element of the complex numbers? I think that would be a nice addition to this answer if you want to be able to say: It's just not always true that: "...". Nothing is always true if you don't specify the domain of the variables :-/. Note that `Solve[-1 == x*x, x]` gives I and -I, but no quaternions and that b*a gets rearranged to a*b which is not true for quaternions.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Yes, Mathematica *generally* assumes that unspecified symbols represent complex quantities. However, certain mathematical functions work only with a proper subset of the complexes. Many number theoretic functions, such as `EulerPhi` work only with the integers, for example. The point behind my answer is that the new `CubeRoot` function assumes the input is real.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I reacted too strongly. I still think that it would be nice if you put in your answer whether you mean that this does not always evaluate to True, or that commonly accepted mathematical definitions make the statement not always true for complex R. I think not everybody may use the definitions Mathematica uses. For example, Mathematica evaluates Log[-1] to I*Pi... More to the point, the way Mathematica defines Power must lead to a discontinous function, if I understand correctly. I can't undo my downvote now, it's locked, but I would love to change that :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom No biggie - I probably deserve downvotes somewhere. Your vote is locked *until* the question is edited, at which point you can change it. But, honestly, I'm a bit confused about your objection. Doesn't the R=i example make it clear that this is a complex/real issue? Of course, your right about the definition thing; ultimately, this is just a choice of branch cut. At any rate, it hardly seems worth worrying about over a question that's been closed anyway!

Comment: One other thing - Is `Power` discontinuous? `Root` definitely is, as you can tell by examining `Plot[Root[a-12 #1+#1^5&,1],{a,-20,0}]` but I think that `Power` is continuous. If I investigate things like `Limit[x^(1/3),x->0,Direction->1]`, I get 0.  You might be interested in this: http://goo.gl/IhDcm That deals with x^x, but x^(1/n) can be treated in a similar way.

Comment: To see that Power is discontinuous, try `z = 1/3;`
`Plot[Im[(-1 + b I)^z], {b, -0.1, .1}]`. This is because `Log[-1+x I]` is discontinuous at x= 0, and Mathematica uses the definition `b^z = Exp[z*Log[b]]` for non integer z. I think :). I agree that the Q&A is not worth it, as its closed, though I definitely don't think the question is too localized. I knew I could change my vote if you edited, that may have been part of the reason I wanted you to edit :).

Comment: And thanks for the link, that answer is rich :)